# Mongo query is too expensive

Tags: mongodb

I am new in mongodb.  I created a query for fetching data from my collection, but that one is too  expensive.

**My collection**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58204f60536d1a27736d512b"),
    "last_name" : "Vinaykumar",
    "university_name" : "Osmania University",
    "job_483" : 1,
    "xiith_mark" : 0,
    "id" : "3305775",
    "first_name" : "V",
    "course_name" : "Diploma",
    "institute_name_string" : "Govt.Polytechnic,Kothagudem",
    "profile_percentage" : 60,
    "xiith_mark_type" : "Percentage",
    "xth_mark_type" : "Percentage",
    "date_of_birth" : "11-March-1995",
    "xth_mark" : 0,
    "last_login" : 1379565790,
    "percentage" : 76,
    "job_details" : [
    {
        "status" : NumberLong(0),
        "applied_date" : NumberLong(1476703354),
        "contact_viwed_status" : 0,
        "label_name" : [ ],
        "questionnaire_status" : 0,
        "batch_id" : null,
        "owner_type" : "searches",
        "call_letter" : null,
        "owner_id" : NumberLong(465)
    },
    {
        "status" : NumberLong(0),
        "applied_date" : NumberLong(1477051963),
        "contact_viwed_status" : 0,
        "label_name" : [ ],
        "questionnaire_status" : 0,
        "batch_id" : null,
        "owner_type" : "searches",
        "call_letter" : null,
        "owner_id" : NumberLong(482)
    },
    {
        "status" : NumberLong(0),
        "applied_date" : NumberLong(1477052973),
        "contact_viwed_status" : 0,
        "label_name" : [ ],
        "questionnaire_status" : 0,
        "batch_id" : null,
        "owner_type" : "searches",
        "call_letter" : null,
        "owner_id" : NumberLong(483)
   }
   ],
   "branch_name" : "Electrical & Electronics",
   "candidate_state_name" : "Andhra Pradesh",
   "candidate_city_name_string" : "Andhra Pradesh-other",
   "10" : 10,
   "12" : 12,
   "gender" : "Male",
   "fw_id" : "FW15651132",
   "cgpa" : 0,
   "picture_path" : "",
   "hq_passout_year" : 2013
}
```

**Query**

```
db.Response.aggregate([
    {"$match":{"$and":[{"job_details.owner_id" : 482},{"job_details.owner_type" : 'searches'}]}}, 
    {$facet: {
        "status": [ 
                        {"$unwind": "$job_details" }, 
                        {"$group": {"_id":"$job_details.status","count": {"$sum": 1 }} }
                     ],
        "label_name": [ 
                        {"$unwind": "$job_details" }, 
                        {"$unwind": "$job_details.label_name" }, 
                        {"$group": {"_id":"$job_details.label_name","count": {"$sum": 1 }} }
                      ] ,
        "contact_viwed_status": [ 
                        {"$unwind": "$job_details" }, 
                        {"$group": {"_id":"$job_details.contact_viwed_status","count": {"$sum": 1 }} }
                      ],
        "questionnaire_status": [ 
                        {"$unwind": "$job_details" }, 
                        {"$group": {"_id":"$job_details.questionnaire_status","count": {"$sum": 1 }} }
                      ],
        "candidate_city_name_string": [ 
                            {"$group": {"_id":"$candidate_city_name_string","count": {"$sum": 1 }}}
                          ],
        "course_name": [ 
                            {"$group": {"_id":"$course_name","count": {"$sum": 1 }}}
                          ],
        "hq_passout_year": [ 
                            {"$group": {"_id":"$hq_passout_year","count": {"$sum": 1 }}}
                          ],
        "branch_name": [ 
                            {"$group": {"_id":"$branch_name","count": {"$sum": 1 }}}
                          ],
        "candidate_sublocation_name_string": [ 
                            {"$group": {"_id":"$candidate_sublocation_name_string","count": {"$sum": 1 }}}
                          ],
        "skill": [ 
                            {"$group": {"_id":"$skill","count": {"$sum": 1 }}}
                          ],
        "doc": [
                        {"$limit":25},
                        {"$skip":0},
                        {"$unwind":"$job_details"}],
        "total_count":[
                        {"$group":{"_id": "null", "count":{"$sum":1}}}]
            }}])
```

This query is too expensive. How can I improve the performance?
Apply for recede which have huge collection.

**My collection detail**
My collection has more than 8 million records. Each record contains embedded records "job_details" each embedded record of contain more than 100 000 data (User details).

I need result of above query. Using that query everything is fine but that is too expensive. The field Job_details contain details user applied jobs of jobs. How can I improve performance?

I am ready to change my collection record format.

My requirement is to get all user details (limit and offset) he applied for particular job id search with owner_id (job_id).

**Needed data:**

facet counts for 9 fields
eg: field "status":[{"0":10},"1":12](in filtered data 10 people have status "0" and 12 people have status "1"     eg:2 field "city_name" 12 peoples in 'bangalore' 20 peoples in 'hydrabad'
and total count (how many users applied for that particular job) and doc:  25 records

**This is the output of my query**

```
 {
      "status": [
        {_id:"1",count:1},
        {_id:"2",count:2}
      ],
      "course_name": [
        {_id:"B.Com",count:1},
        {_id:"12th Pass (HSE)",count:1},
        {_id:"BE/B.Tech",count:1}
      ],
      "branch_name": [
        {_id:"12thpass",count:1},
        {_id:"Food Technology",count:1},
        {_id:"Commerce",count:1}
      ],
      "doc": [
        {
          "10": 10,
          "12": 12,
          "last_name": "Chandr",
          "university_name": "Deemed (Autonomus) University",
          "xiith_mark": 65,
          "id": "3538272",
          "first_name": "Purna",
          "course_name": "BE/B.Tech",
          "institute_name_string": "College of Engineering, Shri Mata Vaishno Devi University, Udhampur",
          "profile_percentage": 55,
          "xiith_mark_type": "Percentage",
          "xth_mark_type": "Percentage",
          "candidate_sublocation_name_string": "Chembur ",
          "date_of_birth": "03-June-1977",
          "xth_mark": 56,
          "last_login": 1448444535,
          "percentage": 65,
          "job_details": {
            "status": 2,
            "applied_date": 1444716448,
            "contact_viwed_status": null,
            "label_name": [],
            "questionnaire_status": 0,
            "batch_id": null,
            "owner_type": "jobs",
            "call_letter": 119,
            "owner_id": 91493
          },
          "branch_name": "Food Technology",
          "candidate_state_name": "Maharashtra",
          "candidate_city_name_string": "Mumbai",
          "gender": "Male",
          "fw_id": "FW15883617",
          "cgpa": 0,
          "picture_path": "",
          "hq_passout_year": 2003,
          "candidate_sublocation_name": "Chembur "
        },
        {
          "10": 10,
          "12": 12,
          "last_name": "",
          "xiith_mark": 0,
          "id": "3538066",
          "first_name": "Liji",
          "last_login": 1434982626,
          "course_name": "B.Com",
          "profile_percentage": 28,
          "xiith_mark_type": "Percentage",
          "xth_mark_type": "Percentage",
          "date_of_birth": "01-January-1970",
          "xth_mark": 0,
          "candidate_state_name": "Gujarat",
          "percentage": 78,
          "job_details": {
            "status": 2,
            "applied_date": 1444368899,
            "contact_viwed_status": 0,
            "label_name": [],
            "questionnaire_status": 1,
            "batch_id": null,
            "owner_type": "jobs",
            "call_letter": null,
            "owner_id": 91493
          },
          "branch_name": "Commerce",
          "candidate_city_name_string": "Ahmedabad",
          "gender": "",
          "fw_id": "FW15883411",
          "cgpa": 0,
          "picture_path": "",
          "hq_passout_year": 2003
        },
        {
          "10": 10,
          "12": 12,
          "last_name": "Xth",
          "job_483": 1,
          "xiith_mark": 67,
          "id": "3538273",
          "first_name": "Purnax",
          "last_login": 1444210762,
          "course_name": "12th Pass (HSE)",
          "profile_percentage": 55,
          "xiith_mark_type": "Percentage",
          "xth_mark_type": "Percentage",
          "candidate_sublocation_name_string": "Bibvewadi ",
          "date_of_birth": "04-June-1956",
          "xth_mark": 76,
          "candidate_state_name": "Maharashtra",
          "percentage": 0,
          "job_details": {
            "status": 1,
            "applied_date": 1444716448,
            "contact_viwed_status": 0,
            "label_name": [],
            "questionnaire_status": 0,
            "batch_id": null,
            "owner_type": "jobs",
            "call_letter": null,
            "owner_id": 91493
          },
          "branch_name": "12thpass",
          "candidate_city_name_string": "Pune",
          "gender": "Male",
          "fw_id": "FW15883618",
          "cgpa": 0,
          "picture_path": "",
          "hq_passout_year": 0,
          "candidate_sublocation_name": "Bibvewadi "
        }
      ],
      "candidate_sublocation_name_string": [
        {_id:"Bibvewadi",count:2},
        {_id:"Chembur",count:1}
      ],
      "contact_viwed_status": [
        {_id:"0",count:2},
        {_id:"1",count:1}
      ],
      "label_name": [],
      "questionnaire_status": [
        {_id:"0",count:2},
        {_id:"1",count:1}
      ],
      "total_count": [
         {_id:null,count:3}
          ],
      "skill": [
        {_id:"None",count:3}
      ],
      "candidate_city_name_string": [
       {_id:"Pune",count:2},
       {_id:"Ahmedabad",count:1}     
      ],
      "hq_passout_year": [
       {_id:"2014",count:1},
       {_id:"2011",count:1},
       {_id:"1999",count:1} 
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Post your expected output

Comment: @ azhar the posted output is my actual output and expected output but performance is problem. That query should take more than 5 sec.   I need a query less than 2 sec

Comment: @cartman619 already indexed all fields interacting in that query

Comment: please lets me know  if any changes needed for my scheema

Comment: @James Z. thanks for edit