# Mongodb Search with embedded document.

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, aggregation-framework

Structure of mongodb collection is like this.
 collection **User**

```
{
"name":"sufaid",
"age":"22",
"address":"zzzz",
"product":[{"id":1,"name":"A"},
            {"id":6,"name":"N"},
            {"id":3,"name":"D"},
            {"id":7,"name":"q"},
        ]
}
```

I need to find users those who have product id **"3"**

**Out put should be like this**

```
{
    "name":"sufaid",
    "age":"22",
    "address":"zzzz",
    "product":{"id":3,"name":"D"}
    }
```

> **Note** : With out using $unwind and projection like  "product.$"

"product.$" through error while using pymongo.
 Any other option is there ???

Comment: You cannot convert an array to object literal without using aggregation framework.with find you can get a output as : {
    "name":"sufaid",
    "age":"22",
    "address":"zzzz",
    "product":[{"id":3,"name":"D"}]
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the aggregation framework which has a plethora of operators that you can use, in particular you'd need the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** and **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt)** operators in a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline.

For instance, you could return just the `product` field as an embedded document by running the following pipeline:

```
db.user.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "product.id": 3 } },
    {
        "$project": {
            "name": 1,
            "age": 1,
            "address": 1,
            "product": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                    {
                        "$filter": {
                            "input": "$product",
                            "as": "item",
                            "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$item.id", 3 ] }
                        }
                    },
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5829ac89628123dcf8a64b7a"),
    "name" : "sufaid",
    "age" : "22",
    "address" : "zzzz",
    "product" : {
        "id" : 3,
        "name" : "D"
    }
}
```

---

If you just need an output with the array filtered, skip the **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt)** expression and use the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** only:

```
db.user.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "product.id": 3 } },
    {
        "$project": {
            "name": 1,
            "age": 1,
            "address": 1,
            "product": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$product",
                    "as": "item",
                    "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$item.id", 3 ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5829ac89628123dcf8a64b7a"),
    "name" : "sufaid",
    "age" : "22",
    "address" : "zzzz",
    "product" : [
        { "id" : 3, "name" : "D" }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

use `$elemMatch`. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

for your query:

```
db.User.find({},{name:1,age:1,address:1,product:{$elemMatch:{id:3}}})
```

or

```
db.User.find({},{product:{$elemMatch:{id:3}}})

o/p:    { 
    "name" : "sufaid", 
    "age" : "22", 
    "address" : "zzzz", 
    "product" : [
        {
            "id" : 3.0, 
            "name" : "D"
        }
    ]
```

### }

As you require it for aggregation:

```
db.User.aggregate([
{$unwind:'$product'},
{$match:{'product.id':3}},
{$project:{_id:0,name:1,age:1,aaddress:1,product:1}}
])
```

o/p:

```
    { 
    "name" : "sufaid", 
    "age" : "22", 
    "address" : "zzzz", 
    "product" : {
        "id" : 3.0, 
        "name" : "D"
    }
}
```

This will give exactly what you indicated in the question.

Comment: how can i implement this thing by using aggregation??

Comment: @SuFi Have you tried my suggested solution? From your question, it seems you are looking for an embedded document and not a single element array `product` field, does that still hold or you are just looking for a document with the given product id?

Comment: @ chridam. ya. i tried this. This is fine. but i need same out put out by using aggregation. (Not find method)

Comment: @ chridam . If we using $unwind no need of projection.(i need with out unwind)

Comment: @ chridam . Sorry . that previous comment not for u. that's to 'cartman619'.

Comment: I saw your update. that's  fine. thats needed output.

Comment: @ chridam. can u check this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541745/mongo-query-is-too-expensive)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.User.find({},{product:{$elemMatch:{id:3}}})
```

it's enough